# update global.asax not only global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Inside my local publish folder I have `Global.asax` and `Global.asax.cs` where Global.asax is not updated (dated one month ago) and Global.asax.cs is updated.

I check the "Build action" of the `Global.asax` file which is set to "Content" and Copy always in the file properties.

> How to update global.asax together with global.asax.cs on publish command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Global.asax` doesn't usually change. `Global.asax` is compiled into a class deriving from the `Global` class in your `Global.asax.cs`.

You don't have to do anything for that. The server's compiler will pick it up itself. You just need to copy the `Global.asax` to your production server, where the `Global.asax.cs` will be compiled into an assembly.

Answer (score 2):

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2(v=vs.71).aspx):

> At run time, Global.asax is parsed and compiled into a dynamically
>   generated .NET Framework class derived from the HttpApplication base
>   class. The Global.asax file itself is configured so that any direct
>   URL request for it is automatically rejected; external users cannot
>   download or view the code written within it.

So as Patrick has already mentioned, there is no need to change it. The compiler will pick it.

> When you save changes to an active Global.asax file, the ASP.NET page
>   framework detects that the file has been changed. It completes all
>   current requests for the application, sends the Application_OnEnd
>   event to any listeners, and restarts the application domain. In
>   effect, this reboots the application, closing all browser sessions and
>   flushing all state information. When the next incoming request from a
>   browser arrives, the ASP.NET page framework reparses and recompiles
>   the Global.asax file and raises the Application_OnStart event.